# Coq: coercion/subtyping between complex expressions

Tags: coq, coercion, subtype

I've got an impression that it's impossible in Coq. For example

```
Parameter Arg: Type.
Parameter F X XP: Arg.
Parameter S P I PLS PI: Arg -> Type.
Parameter tree car: P X.
Parameter mary john: PLS XP.
Parameter c: PLS XP -> P XP.
Coercion c: PLS XP >-> P XP. (*Syntax error: '>->' expected after [vernac:class_rawexpr] (in [vernac:gallina_ext]).*)
```

So not only must the types of the expressions next to `>->` be Set, Type or Prop, the expressions themselves must also be syntactically elementary ("rawexpressions" in Gallina?)? How to bypass this; can I form a coercion between complex expression? Is there another way to define a subtype in Coq, one which would work w/ complex expressions? Can I do better than

```
Let nui := PLS XP.
Let hui := P XP.
Parameter c: nui -> hui.
Coercion c: nui >-> hui.
Parameter st: P XP -> Type.
Check st (c mary). (*st mary : Type*)
Check st mary. (*Error: The term "mary" has type "PLS XP" while it is expected to have type "P XP".*)
```

Answer (score 1):

IMVHO, the setup of the problem is looking very complicated; I am not sure this modeling method will be effective (in the sense of efficient).

If you really want to go that route, note that Coercions have very particular rules; if you want to use them you'll have to get familiar with [chapter 18](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual021.html) of the manual. In particular, I think that parameters cannot be made a source class so you will have to add some wrapping:

```
Parameter Arg: Type.
Parameter F X XP: Arg.
Parameter S P I PLS PI: Arg -> Type.
Parameter tree car: P X.
Parameter mary john: PLS XP.
Parameter c: PLS XP -> P XP.

Inductive p_wrap := p_wrap_C : PLS XP -> p_wrap.
Coercion u_cast x := match x with | p_wrap_C u => u   end.
Coercion c_cast x := match x with | p_wrap_C u => c u end.

Parameter st: P XP -> Type.
Definition Mary := p_wrap_C mary.
Check st (c Mary).
Check st Mary.
```

YMMV. Note that the general `subType` class in ssreflect [doc](http://math-comp.github.io/math-comp/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.eqtype.html) may provide some help on how to make a generic coercion framework.

Comment: Good! I didn't know you can define coercions w/out a prior function declaration. All this is indeed complex (it's mostly my and the manual's fault). I tried something under [chapter 18; Examples](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual021.html#sec674) (will probably make it into an answer after some sleep)

Comment: It's very confusing that you can define a coercion: `Parameter c: PLS XP -> P XP. Coercion c: PLS >-> P. (*Message: c does not respect the uniform inheritance condition*) Print Coercions. (*c*) Print Graph. (*[c] : PLS >-> P*)` and yet there's no coercion: `Check mary:P XP. (*Error: The term "mary" has type "PLS XP" while it is expected to have type "P XP".*)` So the real problem is fulfilling the uniform inheritance condition. `P x` is a superset of `PLS x`, which is an intersection of `P x`, `L x` and `S x`. So I might even pretend that `c` is "a coercion which must be explicitly specified"

Comment: I agree is very confusing; in practice it seems that "does not respect the uniform inheritance" means "your coercion will never be considered for application.

Answer (score 1):

After trying this, that and whatnot, the solution was surprisingly easy. There were two steps my question was missing:

1. You can coerce *functions* towards one another, i.e. `Coercion c: PLS >-> P` works
2. To avoid breaking the ["uniform inheritance condition"](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual021.html#sec657), you must define the function you want to make into a coercion in its general ("forall") form

In sum:

```
Parameter Arg: Type.
Parameter F X XP: Arg.
Parameter S P I PLS PI: Arg -> Type.
Parameter tree car: P X.
Parameter mary john: PLS XP.
Parameter c: forall x:Arg, PLS x -> P x.
Coercion c: PLS >-> P.
Check mary:P XP.
```